# polynomial sum with linked list

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, polynomials

I need to do a polynomial sum using linked lists (C).

Input example:

3 2.5 6 1.5 4 1.0 3
4 2.5 5 1.5 4 1.0 3 5.0 0

The first polynomial has 3 terms, being : 2,5x^6 + 1,5x^4 + 1x^3

Second has 4 terms: 2,5x^5 + 1,5x^4 + 1x^3 + 5x^0

output would be: 5 2.50 6 2.50 5 3.00 4 2.00 3 5.00 0

both in the output and input, the exponents need to be descending.

until now, I've done this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{   
   struct poly
   {
    float coe;
    int Exp;
    struct poli * next;
   };

   struct poli *phead = NULL;


}

struct poli * new_element(float coe, int Exp)
{
    struct poli *p = malloc(sizeof *p);
    p->coe = coe;
    p->Exp = Exp;
    return p;
}
```

I basically created an empty linked list, and the new_element funciton. How do I get the input, with n terms and put it in the list? Really need your help. Thank you.

Comment: "How do I get the input". Well that depends on where the input is supposed to come from which you have not described. "How do I know where one finishes and the other started". You parse the input into an appropriate data structure. There are many ways to do so and you should do research on that. Web search will be your friend there. As it is currently written your question is a bit too broad for Stackoverflow.

Comment: You don't read both polynomials into the same list; you build two lists, and a function that takes two lists and returns a new polynomial.

Comment: @Tordek: it isn't completely clear if OP will always have only two lists? Perhaps the idea is to create one linked list, and then traverse it from the start for each parsed polynomial row, either updating the coefficient or inserting a new node. That's presuming the input is always sorted descending, which also isn't specified.

Comment: struct poli *p = malloc(sizeof *p); Wouldn't this just allocate enough size for the pointer, not the struct?

Comment: @BobbyTables, no, because `*p` is a dereferenced pointer. This is the usual way to do malloc in c, and in my opinion the least prone to errors once you get used to it.

Comment: @Groo, yeah I thought maybe that'd be the case. I've just never seen that before.

Comment: When I first read the exercise, I thought that only one list was allowed. But now, I not sure, so I wil suppose I can use 2 or 3.

Comment: @Groo fair point, but still better to make a list-of-lists than wrangle a way to know where the polynomial begins and ens.

Answer (score 0):

with two lists:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{   

  struct poly2
  {
    float coe2;
    int Exp2;
    struct poly2 * next;
  };

  struct poly2 *phead2 = NULL;


 struct poly1
 {
    float coe;
    int Exp;
    struct poly1 * next;
 };

 struct poly1 *phead = NULL;


}


struct poly * new_element12(float coe2, int Exp2)
{
  struct poly2 *p = malloc(sizeof *p);
  p->coe2 = coe2;
  p->Exp2 = Exp2;
  return p;
}



struct poly * new_element1(float coe, int Exp) 
{
  struct poly1 *p = malloc(sizeof *p);
  p->coe = coe;
  p->Exp = Exp;
  return p;
}
```

Comment: It looks like you are still missing the point of a linked list. You only need a single struct definition, you then allocate instances of the struct as "nodes" and the nodes are related through the `next` pointer. (e.g. each `node->next` holds a pointer to the next node in the list) Example [Singly Linked List](https://pastebin.com/5MPLU4wB) You can create as many lists as you like from the single struct definition.